# RPI 4 and creation of scripts from buildroot

Tags: pi-4, boot, buildroot

I want to know if it is possible to allow my system created by buildroot, to automate the execution of script which would allow for example,

- to switch from qwerty to azerty (maybe this option exists in
  buildroot but I did not find it)
- clone projects in a specific folder
- to execute services
- ...

All this without having to modify anything on the system at startup.

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: your question belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... a linux system can do whatever you program it to do ... for example, it already starts services at bootup time

Comment: Ditto that this would be better off on U&L or SO ([~1500 questions tagged buildroot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbuildroot%5D&searchOn=3)).  This looks to be about configuring the system before it is run (and/or adding a service to do initial configuration at first boot), which might be better off done outside buildroot once the root fs is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - to switch from qwerty to azerty
> - to execute services

You can add a script to `/etc/init.d` in the rootfs overlay (`BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY`).

> - clone projects in a specific folder

This can be done in the post build script (`BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT`).

For details, https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize.